# Toggle switch is resetting in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, toggle

I am new to flutter.
I am adding a toggle switch. Toggle switch is resetting each time after selecting the dropdown I used below the toggle switch.
I have not used any model for the switch.
But I am not sure why the toggle switch is resetting.

```
 NeuCard(
                    curveType: CurveType.flat,
                    bevel: 10,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
                    decoration: NeumorphicDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35),
                      color:Color(0xffecedf1) ,
                    ),
                    child:  Center(
                      child: ToggleSwitch(
                        minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2.5,
                        inactiveBgColor: Color(0xffecedf1) ,
                        activeBgColor: Colors.white,
                        activeFgColor: Colors.black87,
                        labels: genders,
                        onToggle: (index) {
                          selectedGender = genders[index];
                          print('switched to: $index');
                        },
                      ),
                    )
                ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package you are using has an argument called **initialLabelIndex**. There, you can set where the switch "lays" on, every time it initializes.

Create an integer for storing the **labelIndex** before your build function:

```
int initialIndex = 0;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) { ... }
```

Then you set the initialLabelIndex to that value:

```
ToggleSwitch(
  minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2.5,
  initialLabelIndex = labelIndex,
  inactiveBgColor: Color(0xffecedf1) ,
  activeBgColor: Colors.white,
  activeFgColor: Colors.black87,
  labels: genders,
  onToggle: (index) {
    selectedGender = genders[index];
    print('switched to: $index');
    setState(() {
      initialIndex = index; // here you set the initialIndex to the current index.
    });
  },
),
```